# Address RGB header on B450M Pro4

Tags: motherboard, headers

I wnted to play with RGB for a while now. After building a new PC with a case that has some adressable LEDs I was dissapointed to see that ASRocks Polychrome utility has no PI or SDK.

I was wondering, is there a way to speak to the motherboards header directly without the utility?

I got pointed into that direction on a git repository of an open source RGB API for msi MBs. It pointed me to the [datasheet](http://v-comp.kiev.ua/download/NCT6779D.pdf) of the chip used on the B450M Pro4 and is way above my current expertise.

Comment: That datasheet is for a "super I/O" chip that provides a variety of functionality.  It could be connected/control a RGB LED, but you would need a motherboard schematic (or datasheet) to get specific implementation details (e.g. device addresses).  Linux would allow userspace access to hardware (i.e. superuser access to mmap), whereas forget Windows.

Comment: No way on Windows at all?

Comment: You would need a Windows driver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to upgrade your motherboard and get the one that comes with ARGB headers. You can find more information at [RGBAdvisor](https://rgbadvisor.com/) for the most compatible mobo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).